# create_WX() always creates NA

Tags: r, missing-data, spatial

Using `spdep` for R (a collection of tools for spatial econometrics), I wanted to build a regression matrix myself. The matrix is the combination of two matrices, one being the weights matrix and the other one being covariates.

The command to build the matrix that I need is called `create_WX()`. I seem to use it wrongly because it creates a column full with just `NA`.

```
library(spdep)
data(oldcol)
# Build the weights matrix
lw <- nb2listw(COL.nb, style="W")
# Build the covariates matrix
X <- COL.OLD[, c("INC", "HOVAL")]
# Combine
WX <- create_WX(X, lw)
head(WX)
```

outputs

```
         .INC .HOVAL
[1,] 46.67233     NA
[2,] 32.81675     NA
[3,] 35.45417     NA
[4,] 35.40625     NA
[5,] 35.45850     NA
[6,] 45.36475     NA
```

There should be not a single `NA`. I wonder why are they are there and how can I avoid this problem? The documentation for `create_WX()` is unfortunately embedded in `errorsarlm()` and reduces to

> `create_WX` creates spatially lagged RHS variables, and is exposed for
>   use in model fitting functions.

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: @Glen_b: There should be no `NA`s. Please see my edit.